# Splitting polygons and dividing attribute value proportionally using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: polygon, fields-attributes, clip, arcgis-pro, splitting

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.3.0.

I have two feature classes (pictured below), RED polygons and BLUE polygons. The RED polygons have a numeric attribute, Value1.

How can I split the RED polygons with BLUE polygon features and have Value1 be divided proportionally?

i.e. RED feature A has Value1 of 100. If a BLUE polygon split a RED polygon in half, each new RED polygon B & C would have a Value1 (or new field) of 50.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, run MakefeatureLayer to enable the Ratio Policy on a specific field. Then, run the FeatureLayer though Intersect, it will honor the split policy rule. The field specified must be Numeric.